# Nautilus click on mounted partition opens LibreOffice

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, 19.10

I'm running a recent installation of Ubuntu 19.10.

A partition mounted at '/media/USER/Ubuntu_17.10_x64' doesn't appear in the left pane of Nautilus; when I navigate to 'Other Locations' and click on it, LibreOffice starts and an error message pops up: 'Access to /media/USER/Ubuntu_17.10_x64 was denied'

/usr/share/applications/defaults.list doesn't list any relevant LibreOffice extensions as far as I can see (how is a partition identified?).

The sole Nautilus entry reads:
'inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop'

I am able to navigate to the partition from the command console. Files and folders are white rather than coloured, which is a clue to the problem, but permissions look fine.

Can you suggest the cause?

Comment: You will need to investigate the item '/media/USER/Ubuntu_17.10_x64' in more detail. That likely will not be a folder. Anyway, delete it and remount the partition.

Comment: That's the name of the folder in which fstab mounts the partition. I've tried different names, and remounted the partition without effect.

>>drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4096 Nov  7  2018  Ubuntu_17.10_x64

Comment: Can you navigate into the partition using the terminal? Is this a fresh installation or an upgrade?

Comment: It's a fresh installation and I can navigate into the partition from the terminal

Comment: Good information to add to your question. The more you can rule out, the more focus the search for a problem can be.

Comment: All right, seems you sorted it out. Do not hesitate to "Accept" your own answer if that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem seems to be some confused permissions.

The /Home directory pre-dated the installation, and as I wasn't the initial user (UID=1000) I switched UIDs after installation.

Whether because of that or some other reason I noticed that I needed to use sudo to list /media/USER, and directories weren't listed in colour.

I added USER to the USER group as it was missing, and

> sudo setfacl -m u:USER:r-x /media/USER

seems to have corrected the permissions.

I'm now able to view the mounted drives in Nautilus,